# How to deal with high frequency queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that should run every 30 seconds. I am doing so because I want to track if the Cycle Time which is displayed in seconds, decreases or increases for a given timerange. If it execedes the accepted limit, I will get a notification.

Here a more specific display : The aim is to have a cycle time < 60s, because we are working in seconds a one time increase or decrease of the cyle time would not be very meaningful, so what I would do is take the last ten cyle times and calculate the average of it. If this > 60 seconds I will get notified.

***BUT*** To make the tracking as accurate as possible I need the query to run evey 30 seconds. QUERY :

```
    SELECT 

      CAST([Cycletime (s)] as Float) as [Cycletime  (s)]
      ,Machine
      ,Date
      FROM v_Analysis
      WHERE Date >= CAST( GETDATE() AS Date )
```

My question now is how much is the 30 seconds intervall of the query is affecting the performace of the database and if so how do we improve the performance.

Comment: The only way to find the answer to your question is to measure the performance. However I would suggest that running a simple query like that every 30s is not even going to make a blip on an enterprise database.

Comment: `v_Analysis` is presumably a view? We have no idea what the logic behind it is and how many rows you will get on a calendar date and whether or not your query is able to use an index seek to get these efficiently